# How can I create different number of button controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm printing to the screen lots of entries from my database. I'd like each entry to have it's own button, so I can add that specific entry to my cart (saved in `Session[]`).

How can I do it?
I'd like to have something like this: [image]

Thank you very much!! :)

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Do you have any code? There are a few pieces to this puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve that with a repeater or ListView, put a button in the template and give the button an ID of the backend database entry.  When the button is clicked, it fires an event (or if you give a command it fires an ItemCommand event) that you can use to do whatever processing you need...

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the Repeater Control?

- [Repeater Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Repeater control instead of
  grid](http://www.aspcode.net/ASPNET-Repeater-control-instead-of-grid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Brian said, you can add the buttons by using the repeater control. As simple as that.